# Cucumber 4 Junit parallel execution

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

Cucumber 4 now supports parallel execution out of the box using maven surefire plugin. I am using cucumber 4-Junit-RestAssured and spring for DI. However, I am still now able to see multiple threads. I followed same configuration as mentioned in https://grasshopper.tech/464/

```
    Runner.java
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(


      plugin = {

                "timeline:src/test/resources/cucumber-parallel-report",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json"},


        glue = {"com.automation.microservices.step_def"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/"})
public class Runner {

    private static long duration;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Thread Id  | Scenario Num       | Step Count");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after() {
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - duration;
        System.out.println("DURATION - "+ duration);
    }
}
```

My POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- - To use Cucumber 4, exclude the old Cucumber 2 cucumber-core dependency
            from the serenity-core dependency - and include the Cucumber 4 cucumber-java
            and cucumber-junit dependencies. -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Runner.java</include>
<!--                        <include>**/automation/**/*.java</include>-->
<!--                        <include>**/automation/*.java</include>-->
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>both</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
<!--                    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>-->
<!--                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>-->
<!--                    <forkCount>10</forkCount>-->
<!--                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>-->
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Automation Test Report</projectName>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have 2 feature files and Console logs shows Thread Id : 1 for both of them